# How to upload my phonebook contacts into MS SQL server

Tags: android

I want to select my phone book contacts after that upload all my selected contacts into SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

Use 'ContactsContract' to get a Cursor to the contacts, iterate through them, writing them to XML/JSON, say, and then send them to a script on your server to be unpacked and inserted.